# ResignFirstResponder not working.

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar, xib, uicontrol

I want to implement a function that once I touch the table view, the search bar on the top of the view will resignFirstResponder and the keyboard will retrieve from the view. I relate the follow code to the tableView in the xib file but it seems not working.

```
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"test : did touch down");
    [_searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I try another way of implementation by adding the following code in the .m file, but still not working.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"test : did touch down");
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    UIView *view = (UIView *)[touch view];
    if (view == self.view) {
        [_searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Hope that someone could help.

Comment: I am using your second method in a similar situation and it works fine, except on iOS 7, the resignFirstResponder is ignored on the first tap.  Likewise with [self endEditing:YES].  Second tap works correctly.  The fix is to just call resignFirstResponder twice on each tap, and that works.

Answer (score 1):

Just do..

```
[Self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing exactly what you are doing, but call resignFirstResponder twice.  I found that I must do that as of iOS 7.